# How to get the return code from the bash command

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I tried to execute the .sh script in macos using the command below.
i would like to get the return code form the execution of the command

I just tried to return the value form the execution code.

```
processCode=$(bash "test.sh")
return "$processCode"
```

When i run the code i got the error message as

```
"numeric argument required".
```

How to get the return value and get rid of Numeric argument required

Comment: Did you try `echo $?` ?

Comment: `$()` doesn't give you the return code.  (More usually referred to as 'exit status').  It gives you the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
bash "test.sh"
processCode=$?
```